# All possible tuples

Tags: python, python-itertools

```
possible_frequency = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
clamp_range = list(xrange(0, 51, 1))
possible_clamp_levels = int(len(clamp_range)*len(possible_frequency))
print possible_clamp_levels
```

I want to find a way to print all possible tuples (459) using `possible_frequency` and `clamp_range`
 that is, `(0,0),(0,1), (0,2).....(8, 50)`

Is there a package in python that would allow me to do this.

This will do

possible_tuples = []

```
for a in range(0, len(possible_frequency)):
    for b in range(0, len(clamp_range)):
        test = (possible_frequency[a], clamp_range[b])
        possible_tuples.append(test)
print possible_tuples
```

I need a more sophisticated way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product()`:

```
from itertools import product

list(product(possible_frequency, clamp_range))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
for set in itertools.product(possible_frequency,xrange(0, 51, 1)):
    print set
```

product is used for calculating Cartesian product of input iterables.[itertools Product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)